# How do i separate elements in a list with symbols as to elements

Tags: python, string, list, symbols

Sorry if I was unclear with the title

I want to separate the elements in a list of strings with symbols individually  into for example:

```
lines = ['hi!,' , 'how' , 'are' , 'you?'  ]
['hi' , '!' , ',' , 'how' , 'are' , 'you' , '?']
```

I know I can use split('*symbol*') however it will require me to make an expression for every single expression.

Comment: You could use regex. To find each special character, you could use a negative character group-> [^\w\d ]

Comment: Welcome. It would be great if you could include code snippets in the question. One of the potential solutions might include looping through each string and using regular expressions to capture special symbols and extract them. Consider exploring in this direction.

Comment: Hi Lawrence! Can you please show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex that matches either a sequence of alphabetical characters, or a single non-letter:

```
import re

lines = ['hi!,' , 'how' , 'are' , 'you?'  ]

word_or_symbol = re.compile(r'\w+|\W')

out = [item for string in lines for item in word_or_symbol.findall(string)]
print(out)
#  ['hi', '!', ',', 'how', 'are', 'you', '?']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function in the `regexp` package. With this way you can specify the markers you want to use

```
import re

lines = ['hi!,' , 'how' , 'are' , 'you?'  ]

out = [item for string in lines for item in re.split("(!|\?)", string)]
print(out)
```

The key here is the regexp used. The markers `!` and `?` are both separated with the `|` separator character. The `?` marker is escaped `\?` to match exactly that character, because on regexps `?` has other meaning.

Finally, you put all in brackets `()` to get the markers as a separate item in the list. You can remove them if you don't want the markers on the final list.